# How use variables other class?

Tags: php, oop

I have some classes:

```
class A{
    public $D;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->D = new D();
    }
}

class C extends E{
    public function testC(){
        return 'test C';
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->C = new C();
    }

    public function testB()
    {
        echo $this->C->testC();
    }
}
(new B)->testB();
```

I would like transfer variables class A to class C, how i can make it (that i can use variables class A in class C) ?

Comment: There should be `no space` in function name `test C()`

Comment: @SahilGulati it misprint, thx

Comment: if your opinion is "bad question", i will be glad if you give me advice to improve the question or code in question.

Comment: It's not clear at all what are you asking. Show an example of what you are trying to do, explain your expected result, and what are you getting instead when you try it.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to achieve is most likely this.

```
class A
{
    public $variable;
}

class B extends A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->variable = 'value';
    }

    public function testVar()
    {
        echo $this->variable;
    }
}
```

I suggest reading [OOP basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), there is much more to it than this.